# How to get "burned" effect on cheesecake?

Tags: baking, caramelization, cheesecake

I've eaten hot cheesecake in restaurant. It looked like the cheesecake was properly baked and then only a slice of it, which was going to the plate, was fried or baked or I don't know what so it was all warm and crispy and looked like it was slightly burned on the sides.

Any idea how to get this effect? I mean consider I have cheesecake done and I want have just a slice which looks like that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a really good question. I imagine it was probably stabilized with something that stays solid at high heat, b/c hot cheesecake would be fairly soft. Was it warm all the way through? My wild guess would be they rewarmed it in the oven, then (if needed) blasted with a blowtorch for crispiness.

Comment: That "something" is very likely methylcellulose - that tends to be the main agent in any hot dessert.

Comment: The cake was all warm and indeed it had crispy on the outside, yet not really burned by overheating or something.